# tweepy wait_on_rate_limit not working

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So, first off, I realize there's a number of questions regarding handling the twitter rate limits. I have no idea why, but none of the ones's I've found so far work for me.

I'm using tweepy. I'm trying to get a list of all the followers of the followers of a user. As expected, I can't pull everything down all at once due to twitter's rate limits. I have tweepy v 3.5 installed and thus am referring to http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html. To get the list of followers of the originating user I use:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

followerIDs = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=originatingUser, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True).pages():
    followerIDs.extend(page)
```

followers = api.lookup_users(follower)

This works a for a bit but quickly turns into:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Rate limit exceeded', u'code': 88}]
```

My theory, would then to retrieve the followers of each user for each followerID using something like this:

```
for followerID in followerIDs:
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=followerID, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True).pages():
                followerIDs.extend(page)
```

The other problem I have is when I'm trying to look up the user names. For this, It use the grouper function from itertools to break the followers up into groups of 100 (api.lookup_users can only accept 100 id's at a time) and use

```
followerIDs = grouper(followerIDs,100)
for followerGroup in followerIDs:
        followerGroup=filter(None, followerGroup)
        followers = api.lookup_users(followerGroup,wait_on_rate_limit = True)
        for follower in followers:
                print (originatingUser + ", " + str(follower.screen_name))
```

That gets a different error, namely:

```
 TypeError: lookup_users() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit'
```

which I'm finding confusing, becuase the [tweepy api suggests](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#tweepy-api-twitter-api-wrapper) that that should be an accepted argument.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers
Ben.

Answer (score 7):

I know this might be a little late, but here goes.

You pass the `wait_on_rate_limit` argument in the `Cursor` constructor, while the tweepy documentation states that it should be passed on the `API()` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The `wait_on_rate_limit argument` is to be passed in the `API()` constructor.
In your code it would look like:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

There's also another argument `wait_on_rate_limit_notify`, which informs you when tweepy is waiting for your rate limit to refresh. Adding both would finally make the line:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rate limit for twitter API as mentioned here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

The quick solution to pass this could be catching the rate limit error and sleeping your application for a while then continue where you left.

```
pages = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=followerID).pages()
while True:
    try:
        page = pages.next()
        followerIDs.extend(page)
    except TweepError:
        time.sleep(60 * 15)
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

should do the trick. Not sure if this will work as you expect but the basic idea is this.

Comment: Well, yes. I was rather hoping that there was something I was doing wrong with the wait_on_rate_limit thing. It would be a much more ... elegant solution. This does seem to be the only way to go about it at the moment though.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a sensible approach to me - `If an application abuses the rate limits, it will be blacklisted. Blacklisted apps are unable to get a response from the Twitter API`