# Sentiment Analysis storing polarity values gathered from twitter tweets given a range of dates

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, bigdata

Hello I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with storing the polarity values given a specific time frame. So far I have tried downloading all of the tweets containing the word "google" from October 1st 2016 through November 1st 2016

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob
import csv
import time

consumer_key = '' 
consumer_secret = ''

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

#lets authenticate with Twitter which means login via code
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepyapi = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                    q="google", 
                    since="2016-10-01", 
                    until="2016-11-01", 
                    lang="en").items():
   while True:
       try:
           tweet = tweet.next()
       except tweepy.TweepError:
           time.sleep(60 * 15)
           continue
       except StopIteration:
          break

#Write a row to the csv file/ I use encode utf-8
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

As far as the code above, I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Twitter has a QPS limit so I tried implementing `time.sleep`. I tried using what they said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248958/tweepy-wait-on-rate-limit-not-working) .
As far as the sentiment analysis, I plan on using this

```
 #Sentiment Analysis on Tweets
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
```

I think storing all the tweets from Oct 1st 2016 through Nov 1st 2016 would be too much data, thus how do I store the polarity values in the csv file instead? Or would it be possible to store both the tweets themselves and the polarity values in a csv? I want to perform this analysis for the next several months, thus from October 1st 2016 through January 01 2017. My end goal is to plot the trend of the polarity values and see how positive people feel about Google within the next several months